# jupyter notebook scroll to selected cell

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working in a Jupyter notebook that has 100's of cells. I am able to select one the cell from anywhere in the notebook.

For example, selecting cell 8 from the 100th cell. Running the code in 100th cell result in selecting cell8. But the notebook is not scrolling up to cell 8 location. How can i achieve this functionality?

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
display(Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.select([8])"))
```

Something like a ipywidget button click to scroll down to nth cell. Could someone provide idea to achieve this functionality?

Thanks!